# Is it required to upgrade to appium 2.x from appium 1.x if the existing framework is developed in older appium version?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, mobile, automation, appium-android

I have an existing mobile automation framework with 1.x appium code written 7 months back.do we need to upgrade it to appium 2.x so that my scripts won't be failing?
Does Appium stopped supporting desired capabilities n touch actions class in appium 2.x which means since I have code with appium 1.x, my scripts will fail?

Answer (score 0):

I have recently been through this upgrade.

Upgrading to Appium 2 itself is not mandatory but recommended as most of the tools and frameworks depending on it will be doing it considering that it is the future. If you rely on cloud testing platforms, they would have supporting it as it can be difficult for them to maintain the older versions.

[Here](https://appium.io/docs/en/2.0/guides/migrating-1-to-2/) is the official guide on how to migrate and details about what change